# xhtml file is not binding with bean through annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jboss

i have made a simple login page in JSF 2.0 using annotation. I am using eclipse with JBOSS 6.
The Login.xhtml file code is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">


<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Sign-In Page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h3>Sign In</h3>
<h:form>
<!--   Email id: <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.emailid}" id="emailid" size="20"></h:inputText>
<br />
Password: <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" id="password"></h:inputSecret>-->

<h:commandButton value="signin" action="#{loginBean.dologin}" id="signin"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The LoginBean.java code is:

```
    package com;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean" , eager=true)
@SessionScoped

public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7765876811740798583L;

private String emailid = "Madiha";
private String password = "madiha";


public void dologin()
{
    if (emailid.equals("Madiha") && password.equals("madiha")) {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
        // System.out.print("You are logged IN");
    }

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Login error!", "ERROR MSG");
    msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

}

public String getEmailid() {
    return emailid;
}

public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
    this.emailid = emailid;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

When i run this login.xhtml,  their shows only the labels, and No button aor text field.
It seems the Bean class is not properly binded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Wrong JSF tags.** Tag names are 1) case-sensitive and 2) tags that you use belong to another taglib with namespace prefix `h:` as set up in `xmlns` attribute of your `html` element. You should correct `f:inputtext` to `h:inputText`, `f:inputSecret` to `h:inputSecret` and `f:commandbutton` to `h:commandButton`.

**2. Wrong bean properties definition.** As @SJuan76 noted, to use property `#{bean.property}`, you should define public method `public String getProperty(){}` (case sensitive!) in your managed bean.

In order to avoid such problems in future you'd better use some IDE (e.g. Netbeans IDE or Intellij IDEA). IDEs have great autocompletion and validation facilities, especially for JavaEE standard libraries.

**3. You are mixing CDI and JSF dependency injection mechanisms**. Use CDI's `@javax.inject.Named` with `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` or JSF's `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` with `@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`.

**4. Wrong `h:CommandButton` `action` attribute.** JSF Specification (JSP tag documentation / h: / Tag commandButton) says of `action` attribute:

> The expression must evaluate to a public method that takes no parameters, and returns an Object (the toString() of which is called to derive the logical outcome) which is passed to the NavigationHandler for this application

I.e. `dologin()` must not be void. It should return e.g. String outcome, for which navigation rule exists in WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or view name that should be navigated to. E.g. if `dologin()` returns `"success"` user will be navigated to success.xhtml; if `dologin()` returns `"failure"` then user will be navigated to failure.xhtml.

Documentation for JSF is available at jcp.org: [JSF 2.2 spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=344).

If you want to show dialog instead of navigating to different view, you should use `f:ajax` tag with `h:commandButton` in your Login.xhtml to partially render view. You cannot use Swing's `JOptionPane` here, because client-side Swing is irrelevant to server-side JSF.

PS I recommend to download JSF spec for reference and get, for example, "JavaServer Faces 2.0: The Complete Reference" (Ed Burns, Chris Schalk). And, of course, use IDE like NetBeans or Intellij IDEA. It will boost your experience with JSF.

My Login.xhtml that works:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">


<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title>Sign-In Page</title>
</head>
<h:body>
    <h3>Sign In</h3>
    <h:messages/>
    #{loginBean.emailid}
    <h:form>
        Email id: <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.emailid}" id="emailid" size="20"/>
        <br/>
        Password: <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" id="password"/>
        <h:commandButton value="signin" action="#{loginBean.dologin}" id="signin"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have made the change, but no effect

Comment: I have updatet my answer. Take these three steps - and it should work.

Comment: oh! and use `h:head` instead of `head`

Comment: With those kinds of errors, you should be getting tons of logs of error. What do these said?

Comment: @iTollu. Thank you. I have made all the changes u said, edited my above code. But none happens, it is still same results. I dnt know whats wrong

Comment: I've attached my Login.xhtml to answer. It works: renders requested view. Though `dologin()` behaves not as you want it to, fields are rendered normally and form is submited to server. Also, I've added `<h:messages>`: this is where all messages will be output.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues, I am not sure which one is causing the problems

First: The name of the emailid getter/setter is wrong.

You must capitalize the first letter of the property in the getter/setter, so instead of

```
public String getemailid() {... }
```

it should be

```
public String getEmailid() {...}
```

Curiously, you are doing it right for the `password` property.

Second: you are mixing `@ManagedBean` (instantiation through JSF) with `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`. Older versions of JSF used instantiation through JSF and you should be using `@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`. Newer versions use CDI and with them you should use `@Named` instead of `@ManagedBean`

Also to note, when asking questions usually it is worth stating which version of JSF/server/J2EE you are using (without such information, we cannot tell you which annotations you should use).

Comment: I have changed my code, as you says, but still the same result